# onCreate() method is called instead of onNewIntent()

Tags: android, twitter, android-tabactivity

I am developing an application where i have integrated Twitter in TabActivity. I have not created another activity, I am calling intent from TabActivity(Where we add all tabs), If I call intent from another activity it shows black screen. For this i call intent from TabActivity. Now it is  not showing black screen but it is not returning to onNewIntent Function, instead of this onCreate of TabActivity is called.

```
          <activity android:name=".guide.Tab_Custom"      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
 <intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /><category   ndroid:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /><category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" /><data android:scheme="x-oauthflow-twitter" android:host="callback" /></intent-filter>    </activity>
```

Here is code of calling intent:

```
try {
            final String url = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer, Twitter_Constants_Key.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error during OAUth retrieve request token", e);
        }
```

Any idea will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Consider including launchMode to "singleTop".

Comment: thanks for rply. but still not working. onIntent is not called of TabActivity class.

Answer (score 2):

onNewIntent() can be called only if there is an activity already running. Otherwise, onCreate() needs to be called to instantiate the activity.

Comment: I forget now. Its too old. But thanks for the answer.